# Swift type(of:) function signature

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to implement function that returns simple name of value type:

```
func typeName(of value: Any) -> String {
    return String(describing: type(of:value))
}
```

But when I try to call it before `super.init` call:

```
class SuperTest {
    init(name: String) {
        print(name)
    }
}

class Test: SuperTest {
    init() {
//        super.init(name: String(describing: type(of: self)))
        super.init(name: typeName(of: self))
    }
}


Test()
```

it fails with:

> 'self' used before super.init call

which is totally clear to me.

But when I inline `typeName(of:)` body code (commented line) then it compiles and prints expected "Test" result.

Why does this magic happen and how can I use `typeName(of:)` before `super.init()` like `type(of:)`?

Also I can not find any information (function signature) about `type(of:)` in Swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1693602-swift_standard_library_functions) or [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift).

Comment: If you make `typeName` static (as it logically makes sense to be), you won't get this issue.

Comment: It's already defined in global scope. How can I make it more static?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was an instance method. Wait, you can't call a global before the super initializer? Really? :o

Comment: @Alexander It's the passing of `self` as the argument which is the problem

Comment: Yes. That makes sense because `self` is not initialized before `super.init()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it looks like it `type(of:)` is not a function, it is handled statically by the compiler as a [Dynamic Type Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/postfix-self-expression). For this reason you can use it before calling super.init.

With your custom function the compiler doesn't know that you are not actually using the value so it can't allow the call.

Comment: Have you found any documentation for `type(of:)`?

Answer (score 1):

> Also I can not find any information (function signature) about `type(of:)`

Because it is not a function defined by the standard library. It is a *primitive*, i.e. it's part of the language. As the original Release Notes expressed it:

> a new primitive function `type(of:)` has been added *to the language* [emphasis mine]

You might almost think of it as an operator. (That, indeed, was the whole point of its creation, as suggested in the original [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/545e7bea606f87a7ff4decf656954b0219e037d3/proposals/0096-dynamictype.md).)